# Color-coding lookup values

Tags: reporting, charts

When working with picklist options, you can assign charting colors. Is there a way to do this for Lookups?

Example:

Our Opportunities have a Lookup to a custom object, Program, which internally has a designated color (Program A gets yellow folders, Program B gets green, etc. . .) When reporting on Opportunities we would like to assign these "standard" colors to the programs.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may not be able to edit the lookup itself, unless you do a bit of javascript hacking, but how about an IMAGE formula field to show the colour coding

assets.salesforce.com/pdf/getting_started_with_images_v1.pdf

(alternate link: http://www.eltoro.it/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00PA0000007KWj1MAG)

Comment: You can then add this to the lookup search result layouts.  It's the best you'll be able to do I'm afraid.